# How to build GLEW to a custom path?

Tags: glew

I am trying to build GLEW from `git clone https://github.com/nigels-com/glew.git`

According to the website, I can modify the install path using the environment variable `GLEW_DEST` so what I did was

```
export GLEW_DEST=/usr/local/glew
make extensions
make
```

However the compilation shows the following error

```
ld: dylib lib/libGLEW.dylib missing LC_ID_DYLIB load command file 'lib/libGLEW.dylib' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [bin/glewinfo] Error 1
```

can someone help figuring out what is the problem?

Comment: I've just tried with the latest commit of the library and still got the `LC_ID_DYLIB` message. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't had any luck using the provided Makefile to build glew. Hoewever, there is a CMakefileLists that was useful. In order to build glew using cmake, you can check [this issue](https://github.com/nigels-com/glew/issues/13) in glew's github.

Finally, to install it in the desired path, don't forget to add `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<somepath>` to the cmake command.